# Why after updating a custom WordPress theme it doesn't change?

Tags: wordpress, caching, themes, edit

I bought a theme for WordPress and when i try to edit the theme it would not change a thing.

i even deleted images and background from the theme and it somehow still shows up on the page like its being cached somewhere. I cleared my browsers cache and just to be sure i tried to visit the my website on a different computer and the same page shows up.

My question is does WordPress cache images somewhere automatically? if yes is there any way to flush it?

Comment: Where are you making the changes? What is the path where you deleted the images?

Comment: i delete the images through filezilla, i did try to replace the background with the same filename no changes, i try to delete images to see if anything will change and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

WP doesn't cache anything unless you have any caching plugins enabled.  Try disabling all plugins and double checking that the files you deleted are really the ones that you're seeing in your browser.

Right click on any images to get their source then compare them with the path of the image on the server, are they the same?

Comment: good day, @phil thank you for your answer I tried what you've had suggested and i think i found whats causing it. I right click on the images for the source and the difference is its linked to domain.com instead of www.domain.com

Comment: The theme was somehow save in a bare domain location but i could not find it on my server.

Comment: It's possible that domain.com and www.domain.com have different document roots.

I'm not sure what you mean by "somehow save in a bare domain location".  

It would be useful if you could send the website URL so we can check.